# VBS Application.Outlook concurrent usage

Tags: vbscript, outlook, ole

Our automation scripts written in VBScript extensively use the pattern

```
Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(0)
With objMailItem
    .Display
    .Recipients.Add("to@example.com")
    .Subject = "..."
    .Body = "..."
    .SaveAs fileName, 2
    .Close 1
End With
objMailItem = Nothing
objOutl = Nothing
```

Is this a safe pattern to use from concurrently running scripts (under the same user account), or some locking needs to be implemented around it? Assuming it's Windows 10, and latest-ish Outlook version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook uses an STA model, so your calls will be marshaled by the dispatcher to the main thread. There is nothing suspicious there, but I'd recommend creating any scheduling mechanism because the target application will not be able to handle your calls simultaneously.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.